# LWC Viewable in Sandbox's Email Template Builder but not in Production's

Tags: lightning-web-components, email-template

LWC is visible in Email Template Builder in Sandbox under Custom Components but after deploying to Production, I can't see it. It is definitely in the Production org because I can access it in App Builder.

[image: Production]

Have checked that users in both environments have "Access drag-and-drop content builder" and "Manage Public Lightning Email Templates" permissions.

The LWC's XML follows the documentation:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Email Footer</masterLabel>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightningStatic__Email</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
      <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```